# Are non-transferrable Pokemon stuck in Pokemon Home?

Tags: pokemon-home, pokemon-eighth-generation

I had an almost full (missing some event mons) Pokedex in USUM.  I recently purchased a Switch and Pokemon Shield and moved all of my mons to Pokemon Home.

Of course, I afterward discovered that many Pokemon were not transferrable to any of the Generation 8 games.  Given that I don't play Pokemon Go, is there anything I can do with these Pokemon or are they forever stuck in Pokemon Home limbo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything I can do with these Pokemon or are they forever stuck in Pokemon Home limbo?

TL;DR - Yes, but this might require purchasing additional Pokémon games

---

While there are a fair amount of Pokemon that can’t be transferred into Pokémon Sword & Shield,  that doesn’t mean all Pokémon are stuck in Pokémon Home.

At the time of writing, there are three games that are considered Generation 8, which allow connectivity to Pokémon Home, and some games support Pokémon that others do not :

- Pokémon Sword & Shield
- Pokémon Brilliant Diamond/Shining Pearl
- Pokémon Legends Arceus

However, these are still many species that are not supported in any Generation 8 game. With Generation 9 (Scarlet & Violet) coming out within a few weeks, additional Pokémon can be used in the future (though Pokemon Home may or may not be supported at launch, that awaits to be seen).

Outside of transferring them in and out of home, you can still always use them for trading within Home (on the mobile version). Since USUM requires a pokemon bank sync to move them into home, certain species from Generation 7 may be more difficult to come by (which was my experience when completing the national dex in home). As such, you might have more trading power respectively speaking

Comment: But there are Pokemon which cannot be transferred to **any** Gen 8 game, right?

Comment: @DanielWalker That is correct, unfortunately